# Cuando escribo el comando git push origin master me sale este error

Tags: git, github, git-push

Este es el error que me viene saliendo luego de  escribir el comando para subir mi proyecto a mi repositorio.

```
C:\Users\user\source\repos\seleniumTest>git push origin master
To https://github.com/miNombre/miRepositorio
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/miNombre/miRepositorio'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: te dice que vas a subir a master algo, pero alguien ha actualizado el master en remoto (y no tienes esos cambios). Para corregir ese error, tienes que hacer primero un `git pull`(bajarte los cambios actuales), mergear y revisar errores si te salen, y luego hacer otro commit con todos esos cambios. Una vez hecho, podras hacer el `git push`

Answer (score 8):

Alguien ha modificado la rama `master` de tu servidor remoto (lo normal es porque alguien ha creado commits en la rama y ha pusheado los cambios).

Por tu parte también has hecho cambios en la rama `master`, por lo que hay una divergencia entre lo que hay en remoto y lo que hay en local.

En el mensaje de error te recomienda que te descargues los cambios en local, elimines esa divergencia y después intentes pushear otra vez.

Puedes hacer eso haciendo `git pull` y después `git push`.

Cuando haces `git pull`, por una parte sincronizas tu rama `origin/master` con la rama `master` que haya en el servidor remoto. Ojo estoy hablando de la rama `origin/master`, no de la rama `master`.

Lo siguiente que hace `git pull` es intentar poner tu rama `master` encima de tu rama `origin/master` que ya está sincronizada en el paso anterior.

Esto lo puede hacer por dos estrategias, puede intentar mergear tu ramaorigin/master sobre tu rama master (estrategia por defecto) o puede intentar poner tu rama master sobre tu rama origin/master (rebase). El resultado va a ser igual en cuanto al estado que tendrá la rama master al final, pero la estructura del árbol será distinta (generalmente el árbol resultante es menos complejo si se hace rebase).

Aquí, si todo va bien, se acabaría con éxito el pull, pero es posible que tengas un conflicto si las zonas de los ficheros donde ha habido cambios son cercanas. Este posible conflicto lo puedes resolver ejecutando `git merge-tool` y después añadiendo los ficheros que has modificado en la resolución con `git add`. Si no tienes conflicto no tienes que hacer nada de esto.

Una vez hayas resuelto el posible conflicto, ya tendrías tu rama `master` en relación fast-forward con la rama `origin/master`, esto es, no existe divergencia entre las dos ramas y tu rama master está encima de tu rama origin/master, por lo que ya puedes hacer git push.

Aunque estemos hablando de conflictos, divergencias, "alguien ha modificado la rama `master`", no hay que alarmarse, ya que este es el flujo normal de trabajo con otras personas con git, ese mensaje te sale simplemente porque otra persona ha subido cambios a `master` antes que tú, y ahora simplemente te avisa para que tengas cuidado para no machacar el trabajo de la otra persona.

Comment: cuales son los posibles comandos para poder eliminar esas divergencias por favor.

Comment: @FrancoAnelUbaldeArenas He editado la respuesta para clarificar los comandos necesarios que tienes que ejecutar